# Verificar um padrão de caracteres para login

Tags: c#, .net, string, regex

Ao usar a classe `Regex` do C#

Eu queria que a *string* `nomeLogin`

- não permitir que comece com números ou caracteres especiais.
- apenas permitir "_" ou "-" ou "." como caracteres especiais.
- mínimo de 2 caracteres sendo o primeiro letra e minúsculo.
- máximo de 20 caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que isto dá certo, não testei e não garanto que está pegando todas situações:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RegExLogin.cs).

Também não sei se você especificou corretamente o que precisava. A especificação já está esquisita dizendo o que não pode, o mais correto é dizer o que pode.

Answer (score 2):

bom eu consegui resolver, então pra quem precisar ta aí a resposta testada:

```
var regex = new regex("^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9_.-]{1,19}$");
```